# How to write a method that reads input from a keyboard (up to 40 numbers) and stops reading at (-999)

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prototype {       
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int values = new int[40];
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter 40 numbers:");
        String input = kbd.nextInt();
    }
}
```

This is the code I have at the minute and is as far as I got, my knowledge on arrays is pretty limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int i =0;
while(i<40) {
 int number = input.next();
 if(number== -999) {
   break;
 }
 i++;
}
```

Comment: If you want to store them, then you can use an array. otherwise no use.

Comment: thank you so much for your help@AnshulJain it really is appreciated, at least I have a better idea on how to approach the rest of the problem